# Svelte - Extract value from #each block and pass in function

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

Using svelte I like to capture a value (e.g. car-price) when the button is pressed within an #each block in order to pass it to another component.

Code example:

```
<script>
  import TeslaStore from "../stores/TeslaStore.js";

  const cars = $TeslaStore.filter((e) => e.name === "Model S");
</script>

{#each cars as car}<button>{car.label} {car.price}</button>{/each}
```

I am aware that for a simple extraction you could use an on:click callback function like:

```
on:click(() => price = car.price)
```

But this doesn't help me because I actually need to call and run a function that can pass that value on.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can call a function in an each block with the newly selected price.

```html
<script>
    let selectedPrice;
    const cars = [
        {
            name: 'car 1',
            price: '2000'
        },
        {
            name: 'car 2',
            price: '4000'
        }
    ]
    
    function handlePriceSelection(newPrice) {
        selectedPrice = newPrice;
        // do whatever else you need to with the new price
    }
</script>

{#each cars as car}
    <button on:click={() => handlePriceSelection(car.price)}>
        {car.name} (${car.price})   
    </button>
{/each}

<div>
    Selected price: {selectedPrice}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use higher-order functions to accomplish this sort of thing:

```html
<script>
  import TeslaStore from "../stores/TeslaStore.js";

  const cars = $TeslaStore.filter((e) => e.name === "Model S");

  // This creates a function for a specific car.
  const selectsCar = (car) => { /* ... do something with car.price ... */ }
</script>

{#each cars as car}
  <button on:click={selectsCar(car)}>{car.label} {car.price}</button>
{/each}
```

> I actually need to call and run a function that can pass that value on.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish (and apologies if I'm off base with this suggestion), you can get this value "out" of the component using `createEventDispatcher`, exported from svelte.

```js
// Reworked from previous example:
import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
const selectsCar = (car) => dispatch('select-car', car);
```